# Moving a vector into an unordered_set

Tags: c++, vector, move, unordered-set

I have a `vector<T>` that I would like to initialize `unordered_set<T>` with. `vector<T>` will never be used again afterwards.

How I've been doing it is the following

```
std::vector<T> v{ /* some large amount of data, typically strings */ };
std::unordered_set<T> ht;
std::move(v.begin(), v.end(), std::inserter(ht, ht.end()));
```

I am wondering if there's a more direct way to do this with `unordered_set` constructor? Its move constructor doesn't take in a vector.

Comment: Does `std::back_inserter(ht)` actually compile? I thought `back_inserter` needs the object to have `push_back`.

Comment: Shouldn't that move statement be : `std::move(v.begin(), v.end(), std::inserter(ht, ht.end()));` ?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oops, you're right! I was more pseudocoding up there to illustrate a point, but didn't realize that what I had was invalid.

Comment: To be precise, you cannot move a `vector` into an `unordered_set`, you can only move its contents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This solution actually requires more characters, but it does express the intent more directly:

```
std::unordered_set<T> ht(std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()),
                         std::make_move_iterator(v.end()));
```